# How to access class-scope variables without self?

Tags: python, class, static, scope

So I have a class, which I'm using as a local namespace. I have some static functions in the class, but they can't access the class scope variables. Why is this?

```
class Foo:
    foo_string = "I am a foo"

    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        print foo_string
```

---

```
>>> Foo.foo()
  [Stack Trace]
  NameError: global name 'foo_string' is not defined
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Python doesn't let class variables fall into scope this way, there are two ways to do this, the first is to use a class method:

```
@classmethod
def foo(cls):
    print(cls.foo_string)
```

Which I would argue is the best solution.

The second is to access by name:

```
@staticmethod
def foo():
    print(Foo.foo_string)
```

Do note that in general, using a class as a namespace isn't the best way to do it, simply use a module with top-level functions instead, as this acts more as you want to.

The reason for the lack of scoping like this is mainly due to Python's dynamic nature, how would it work when you insert a function into the class? It would have to have special behaviour added to it conditionally, which would be extremely awkward to implement and potentially fragile. It also helps keep things explicit rather than implicit - it's clear what is a class variable as opposed to a local variable.

Comment: In 3.x class compilation, any function that references `__class__` becomes a closure. The cell for `__class__` is set by the new `__build_class__` built-in function. `staticmethod` is removed from 3.x, so a plain function defined in a class can reference `__class__`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The main reason I'm not using a module as a namespace is that I have nested classes for nested namespaces, and it's unwieldy to manage so many small files.

Comment: Coming from Java and having the habit to try to encapsulate the data in classes (which is less convenient in python because of self. and less useful because of dynamic type allocation) this answer just lit up a lightbulb. Still not sure how to properly use python in a pythonic way and keep my code clean though.