# Variable in class scope not found in conditional dict comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, scope, python-3.7

Consider the following code:

```
class A:
    ID = 5
    VALUES = ((4, "four"), (5, "five"))
    MAP = {
        t[0]: t[1] for t in VALUES if t[0] != ID
    }
```

This is surprising (to me), because the `VALUES` symbol is found correctly, but the code gives the error "NameError: global name 'ID' is not defined".

Having just `t[0]: t[1] for t in VALUES` works. Why?

Comment: try t[0]: t[1] for t in VALUES if t[0] != A.ID refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037426/how-to-access-class-scope-variables-without-self

Comment: @Pradam: No, A is not in scope at that point.

Comment: A is not in scope at that point?

Comment: No. (Try it!). 123

Comment: See [Accessing class variables from a list comprehension in the class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition)

Answer (score 3):

There is an [excellent and very detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13913933/8787680) on the subject in the question pointed by [@t.m.adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7811673/t-m-adam).

The short answer is:

> Names in class scope are not accessible. Names are resolved in the
>   innermost enclosing function scope. If a class definition occurs in a
>   chain of nested scopes, the resolution process skips class
>   definitions.

As for the solution, I believe the easiest way to achieve the desired result is to create the variable inside the `__init__` function as follow:

```
class A:
    ID = 5
    VALUES = ((4, "four"), (5, "five"))

    def __init__(self):
        self.MAP = {
            t[0]: t[1] for t in self.VALUES if t[0] != self.ID
        }
```

If you print the result of `self.MAP`, you will get the following:

```
>>> my_instance = A()
>>> print(my_instance.MAP)
{4: 'four'}
```