# Error when using lists in classes in Python 3.9

Tags: python, list, class

This is the code:

```
class Deck:
    suits = ['Spades', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts']
    nums = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
    deck = [f"{j} of {i}" for j in nums for i in suits]
    #print(deck)
```

But when it compiled, it gave me this error:

```
deck = [f"{j} of {i}" for j in nums for i in suits]
```

NameError: name 'suits' is not defined

I have literally no idea why--although I am pretty new to OOP and trying to test it out on some of my projects.

Comment: Not exactly, but thanks

Comment: The weird thing is that--the list 'nums' prints out fine if i remove 'suits', but not if i keep them both

Comment: What is your expected output in `[f"{j} of {i}" for j in nums for i in suits]`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error on py3.6 - https://trinket.io/python3/136656d45b

Comment: @ChatoPaka the code you listed there is not inside a class (here it is inside `class Deck`)

Comment: @Countour-Integral: ['2 of Spades', '2 of Clubs', '2 of Diamonds', '2 of Hearts', '3 of Spades', '3 of Clubs', '3 of Diamonds', '3 of Hearts', '4 of Spades'.... and so on]

Comment: The bare variable declarations inside the `class` do not look inside the class unless you ask them to. They can't until the class is actually defined. Basically duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037426/how-to-access-class-scope-variables-without-self

Comment: It works totally fine if i'm running the code outside of the class, but errors come in when I'm running it inside of the class.